# remove dimnames of data.frame using unname doesn't work

Tags: r, dataframe, names

I tried to remove both rownames and colnames of a data.frame. As Jason saied, this can be done with `unname` then set rownames to `NULL`. I noticed that the manual says using `unname` with option `force = T` would do the same thing in single step:

> force  logical; if true, the dimnames (names and row names) are
>   removed even from data.frames.

however, this doesn't work for me:

```
d <- data.frame(a = c(x1 = 1, x2 = 2), b = c(x1 = 'a', x2 = 'b'))
unname(d, force = T)

# Error in `dimnames<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = NULL) : 
#   invalid 'dimnames' given for data frame
```

what is the reason?

```
sessionInfo()
# R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
# Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
# Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
# 
# locale:
#  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
#  [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
#  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
#  [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
#  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
# [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
# 
# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weird. Looks like a bug from here (code behaviour doesn't match documentation).

As a work-around, to remove the rownames, you'll need to:

```
> d <- unname(d)
> rownames(d) <- NULL
> d

1 1 a
2 2 b
```

The left-most column of numbers is R's standard `data.frame` row numbering and is applied to `data.frame`s without rownames.

Comment: hi. I know `unname(d)` could remove colnames and `rownames(d) <- NULL` could remove rownames. I want to know why unname with `force` doesn't work here.

Comment: There isn't much to the code of unname, so I'm thinking a bug report might be in order. What you've shown here is sufficient; a copy-and-paste would likely do nicely.  https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/

Comment: Also interesting is that you can create a `data.frame` that you can't copy the dimension names from - `d2 <- d; names(d2) <- NULL; dimnames(d) <- dimnames(d2)` gives an error.

Comment: hi, @Jason. I can't report this bug. It says 'NOTE: due to abuse by spammers, since 2016-07-09 only users who have previously submitted bugs can submit new ones on R’s Bugzilla'.

Comment: Please confirm a) the most recent version of R for which this doesn't work and b) if/when a bug is raised on R-Forge, the commit/expected version for a fix

Answer (score -1):

in case you need a solution for your data but doesn't give answer for why does **force = T** not working.

```
#read data
d <- data.frame(a = c(x1 = 1, x2 = 2), b = c(x1 = 'a', x2 = 'b'))
```

[image: original data]

```
#convert to matrix
m1 <- as.matrix(d) 
#remove dimnames
m2 <- matrix(mm1, ncol = ncol(d), dimnames = NULL)
m2 #output the data
```

[image: result]

Seems that **unname()** is not working for **data.frame** even if does say it works in documentation.

Comment: "as.matrix()" converts the numeric column to character (strings). Be careful.